SQL query that calculates percentages in a column of a large data set
Query to calculate the percentage of sales along the column sales of a large data set
Below is the query I came up with and the output I got:
SELECT 
    BRANDS,
    BRANDS_sales,
    (BRANDS_sales / total_sales * 100) AS sales_percentage
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         BRANDS, 
         SUM(PROFIT) AS BRANDS_sales,
         (SELECT SUM(PROFIT) FROM Breweries_practice1) AS total_sales
     FROM 
         Breweries_practice1
     GROUP BY 
         BRANDS) AS sales_data;

The output:
BRANDS      BRANDS_sales    sales_percentage
--------------------------------------------
beta malt   8754410         0
grand malt  7577340         0
castle lite 34606980        0
budweiser   31568500        0
trophy      6402950         0
eagle lager 10224240        0
hero        6453000         0

I expected values for the percentage other than zeros

What is the datatype of each column? What does the raw data look like?
